How to use `pwsh` instead of powershell on gitlab?
Here is my simple scenario: I'd like to execute some minimal smoke test in an image I build. The following works nicely:
docker 2022:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
  script:
    - echo "Hello World!"

Now if I use an image where powershell is missing (but pwsh is present), the following fails:
pwsh sdk 7:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
  script:
    - echo "Hello World!"

From reading other post on SO I stumble upon:

Gitlab runner configuration on windows

But that does not seems appropriate for me (we are using gitlab SaaS) and I do not want to change the existing "powershell" runner (ref).
Is there any other mechanism where I could build a docker image so that 'pwsh' is being used in place of 'powershell' (AFAIK syntax are equivalent).

For reference failure is:
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1 (f5da3c5a)
  on Windows-Docker-runner-2 [...]
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 ...
Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:e01215b24dc6dc2849927b4f1a828bc7f5535fe1d45ab3eafb55f6e4c376e65a for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:e44ea6d4cd019913b80726896e1127cd3fd6bd0f5c1d2074be02da3e54931127 ...
[...]
Getting source from Git repository
Skipping Git repository setup
Skipping Git checkout
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:e01215b24dc6dc2849927b4f1a828bc7f5535fe1d45ab3eafb55f6e4c376e65a for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:e44ea6d4cd019913b80726896e1127cd3fd6bd0f5c1d2074be02da3e54931127 ...
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: container 937a9b5bca31aca5aed9a4bc75e286d5d5cae1ab8d7af4d83a60eff9c688fb75 encountered an error during hcs::System::CreateProcess: powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command -: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) (exec.go:78:1s)

Where:
...
[[runners]]
  name = "Windows-Docker-runner-2"
  executor = "docker-windows"
  shell = "powershell"
...

pwsh seems to be working:
> docker run mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 pwsh --version
PowerShell 7.3.11


There is a hack, I figured out, to make PowerShell NanoServer image running with GitLab Docker runner based on shell "powershell":
.nanoServerPowershell:
  tags:
    - <Your Docker Runner Tag>
  image:
    name: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809
    docker:
      user: ContainerAdministrator # Required to create the symbolic link
    entrypoint:
      - "pwsh"
      - "-Command"
      # ";" at end of pwsh command required!
      - 'New-Item "$($Env:ProgramFiles)/Powershell/powershell.exe" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target "$($Env:ProgramFiles)/Powershell/pwsh.exe" | Out-Null;'


Here is my current hack-ish solution:
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

# Cannot use mklink on nanoserver for now:
# https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37024
# RUN mklink /h "C:\Program Files\powershell\powershell.exe" "C:\Program Files\powershell\pwsh.exe"

# plain copy for now:
RUN copy "C:\Program Files\powershell\pwsh.exe" "C:\Program Files\powershell\powershell.exe"

